# Writing the GPA in the application form, even though the studies have not finished yet

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, gpa

In the application form of the master's program that I'm applying for, I'm obligated to write my GPA, and I cannot leave it blank, as the form cannot be submitted in that case. I still have one more semester to complete my Bachelor's degree studies.

What do you suggest to write in the field? Should I simply write my GPA, or should I add any phrases afterwards such as: **4.9 out of 5 (5 semesters)**

Comment: I would write your current GPA, and not an estimated one. The GPA would be the same as what your transcript would say if you obtained one the instant you submitted. Other than that, you can call the office and verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your current GPA, and just say: "Current GPA: N.N" if the field allows you to add text and not just a number.  It is the current truth, and the people who are reading it will understand that it cannot reflect classes that you have not yet taken.